# Swift : Navigation bar should be stick on to the TOP

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I wan to stick my navigation bar on top for every pages that i have in app.

### I have my Code below

```
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle =   UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent
    navigationController?.navigationBar.opaque = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent=true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0.4
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.4)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor =  UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
```

What can i do to just stick navigation bar?

Thanks,
Dhaval.

Comment: What do you mean stick? What does it do now? Why are you hiding it?

Comment: @Wain ..I ment to say that..it should be stick on top of the page and should not be hiding it any tap or swipe action...even i have edited my code to {navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = false}          but it is not working correctly...bar is not showing in this case...Please advise

Comment: use optional unwrapping to check your `nagivationController?` to see if it `nil` or not

Comment: @PhamHoan How would i check that? Sorry i am bothering you..

Comment: `if navigationController == nil {println("Something")} else {println("something else")}`

Comment: @PhamHoan it is coming as not nil...i just want to stick to my app but it is not appearing...can you please give me some example code for this??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here some guide, assume that you're a do-everything-by-code guy.

In app delegate:

```
let tempVC = UIViewController()
tempVC.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController:tempVC)

window?.rootViewController = navVC
```

it should work.
Then you do your `navigationBar` customization code in here or in your viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved

### Code below

```
 navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor =  UIColor.whiteColor()
 navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent
 navigationController?. navigationBar. hidden=false
```